# why my jsoup.connect(url) can not work with some url?

Tags: java, jsoup, connect

I am trying to fetch title from  http://tv.atmovies.com.tw/tv/attv.cfm?action=channeltime&channel_id=CH06

Here is the part of my source code :

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect( theurl above ).get();

Element title = doc.select("title");

textview.setText(title);
```

This code can work when I'm trying to fetch the title from `www.yahoo.com`.
But it can't work with the url like `http://tv.atmovies.com.tw/tv/attv.cfm?action=channeltime&channel_id=CH06` Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

By default Jsoup follows [redirects](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#followRedirects%28boolean%29). However your problem can be caused by how the redirect ist done. If the website uses javascript for this, the connection wont get redirected since jsoup doesn't support javascript.

And that seems to be the reason ...

**Testcode:**

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://tv.atmovies.com.tw/tv/attv.cfm?action=channeltime&channel_id=CH06").get();
System.out.println(doc);
```

**Output:**

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script language="javascript">if (top.frames.length != 0) { top.location = self.document.location; }</script> 
  <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;URL=/home/" /> 
 </head>
 <body></body>
</html>
```

As i said: Jsoup doesnt support javascript and wont get redirected here.

Btw. do you realy need a connection to this link? the only thing it does is a redirect to *home* page. So maybe your url is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

This website **`http://tv.atmovies.com.tw/tv/attv.cfm?action=channeltime&channel_id=CH06`**" redirects to **`http://www.atmovies.com.tw/home/`**.

Comment: Thank you for reply so fast, but how to solve the redirect problem?